Interchanging Bounds in Double Integrals (When Bounds are Functions of y or x)
Let me set the scene, we have a domain of a function of two variables $f(x,y)$.
$$D = \{(x,y): a \leq x \leq b, g_1(y) \leq y \leq g_2(y)\}$$
So on the $y$-axis it's bounded by two functions. So when evaluating the integral I'll use those two functions as bounds, however if these two functions can also be described as a function of $x$, where it's one-to-one, could I instead also write the bounds as functions of $x$?

I guess the bound of $y$ need to bea function of $x$ instead of $y$, otherwise after integrating variable $y$, you still get the $y$ in the integrand.

What do you mean by "can also be described as functions of $x$"?  $g_1(y)$ or $g_2(y)$ denotes a function of $y$.  There is no $x$ there for it to be a function of.  If it depended on $x$ as well as $y$, it might be written as $g_1(x,y)$ or $g_2(x,y)$, but not as $g_1(y)$ or $g_2(y)$.
